# Upload a file to dropbox with PHP

Tags: php, dropbox-php

been trying to get the PHP example listed on the dropbox website (https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/php) to work... but just keep getting server errors and a blank white page... I have added in the url to my json config file along with the autocode I have got from Dropbox... what else is wrong??

```
<?php

# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("config.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();

echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "\n";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).\n";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code.\n";
$authCode = "AuthCodeXXXXXX";

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
print "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

print_r($accountInfo);

$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/working-draft.txt", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);

$folderMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/");
print_r($folderMetadata);

$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);
```

Comment: Add the errors to your question..

Comment: I cant see the errors - looking in firebug I can just see a server error... I can just see "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: If PHP gives you a blank white page when it errors, it usually means you have the `error_reporting` setting switched off. You can switch it on in the PHP config (php.ini or .htaccess, etc). You should also be able to see the error details in the server's error log file.